# Firebase .indexOn dynamic keys

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've started testing Firebase and I can't figure out one thing about indexing. I'm creating a structure based on what I've read on - [Firebase Data Structuring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data) - something like that example with Users and Groups. JSON tree looks something like this:

```
{
  "babies" : {
    "-KQSVCXI-ZMz_lQ_Q906" : {
      "name" : "Baby",
      "parents" : {
        "F0o8Gr5GC2SrakUYZpC20efcmk63" : true
      }
    },
    "-KQSf4t9XQC3LnbsxLYS" : {
      "name" : "Name2",
      "parents" : {
        "S6aO6Dx4lgg6anW9S9hu7EJrhVg1" : true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I'm trying to get babies for a parent - just like there were members in groups in a Firebase example. I'm doing that in the iOS Application by using:

```
self.babiesReference
                .queryOrderedByChild("parents/\(user.uid)")
                .queryEqualToValue(true)
                .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
                
                // Print value
                print(snapshot.value)
                
            }
```

where `user.uid` is current user's id. This works fine but the only problem that remains is this:

> Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn":
> "parents/S6aO6Dx4lgg6anW9S9hu7EJrhVg1" at /babies to your security
> rules for better performance

How to index this "dynamic" child presented by user's id? Is there a way to do it or must I change the tree structure?

Thanks.

Comment: Security rules allow dynamic keys with variables. I'm not sure if indexing supports those too but it's worth trying. See here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security. Rule is enforced on /users/$user_id which secures any key below /users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this type of query (and in general when you get into requiring adding indexes dynamically) you'll likely need to set up an inverted index. In your case:

```
{
  "babies" : {
    "-KQSVCXI-ZMz_lQ_Q906" : {
      "name" : "Baby",
      "parents" : {
        "F0o8Gr5GC2SrakUYZpC20efcmk63" : true
      }
    },
    "-KQSf4t9XQC3LnbsxLYS" : {
      "name" : "Name2",
      "parents" : {
        "S6aO6Dx4lgg6anW9S9hu7EJrhVg1" : true
      }
    }
  },
  "parents": {
    "F0o8Gr5GC2SrakUYZpC20efcmk63": {
      "babies": {
        "-KQSVCXI-ZMz_lQ_Q906": true
      }
    },
    "S6aO6Dx4lgg6anW9S9hu7EJrhVg1": {
      "babies": {
        "-KQSf4t9XQC3LnbsxLYS": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This type of bidirectional linking is fairly common in Firebase (and in many similar NoSQL databases).

Comment: Alright, thanks for this. But how do I setup ".indexOn" in this case?

Comment: Since you're only accessing keys here, no custom indexes are needed (keys are automatically indexed). If you're still getting a warning about missing indexes with the above structure, show the code of your query and the warning you get.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I've still to test this but I'm sure this is the only proper way to make it work. Cheers

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen How much time does it take for indexOn to work? I mean if I added indexOn to an existing data does work immediately?
Or should I wait few minutes till the index is built?

Comment: Indexes are created immediately when you save the rules that define that index.