# Firebase indexes on dynamically created keys

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use Firebase index on the realtime database, the problem I have is that the data key is created programmically and has an incremental value at the end of the key.

For example;

match_01, match_02, match_03, etc...

The structure is;

```
- Matches
 - Match_01
  - played
  - hometeam
  - awayteam
```

etc....

I've look at how to setup Firebase rules that defines the index, but this seems to only be applicable to known data, not data that has a dynamically generated key. The code below for example won't work as the parent of played is Match_01, Match_02, etc...

```
{
"rules": {
"Matches": {
  ".indexOn": ".played"
  }
 }
}
```

Does anyone know how to set an index against this type of data structure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase .indexOn dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238374/firebase-indexon-dynamic-keys)

Comment: Three things; take a look at that answer @AndréKool linked as it's spot on. You don't need indexOn with that structure (assuming you read the node by key) since keys are automatically indexed. Howerver - an this is the important part. It may be a good idea to disassociate your keys from you data - in this case generate your key with push() or childByAutoId and then make the match number/name a child. e.g.: */generated_key/match_num: 01* and */generated_key/match_num: 02* etc. and then add .indexOn to the *match_num* node. It really depends on your use case but that's common practice.