# Firebase realtime .indexOn

Tags: firebase, react-native, indexing

after reading quite some about .indexOn I thought I understood how it worked but it seems I am still a bit lost for one case.

My trouble is that I am getting a warning on .indexOn on the tag search that I am doing as follow :

```
postRef
 .orderByChild(`i/tags/${tag}/a`)
 .equalTo(1)
```

`${tag}` being the searched tag

I have the following structure : 
[image: structure]

And rules :

```
"posts": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null",
      ".indexOn": "i/ts",
      "$pid": {
        "i": {
          "tags": {
            ".indexOn": "a",
          },
        }
      }
    },
```

from what I understood my wildcard should work for the postId and the .indexOn should work in this case but I get the warning at every search

The warning I am getting is :

```
[Firebase/Database][I-RDB034028] Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "i/tags/test/a" at /posts to your security rules for better performance
```

Comment: Please check the following post - https://stackoverflow.com/q/39238374/2765346. I think that here you will find the answer :)

Comment: What warning did you get?

Comment: @tuledev I just added the warning I am getting

Comment: @HristoEftimov it seems to be a work around more than the answer that I am trying to find or maybe this is impossible to achieve in my current state ? :)

Comment: @CladClad Yes, I think that you cannot achieve it in this data model... you need to change it :)

Comment: @HristoEftimov Sad but at least it's an answer xD do you know the reason why it's not possible is it because of the double dynamic keys level ?

Comment: I guess so... Frank van Puffelen, the author of the answer that I sent you, is an engineer for Firebase and he offers this is a solution. Unfortunately, I couldn't find another solution to this problem or any describe why this is not possible. I have also faced with the same deep dynamic key and I had to change the data model.

Comment: @HristoEftimov okay sounds fair and if it comes from the tech of firebase indeed I will do it this way thanks for your help

Comment: @CladClad Please, accept my comments like advice/helpful resources, not like a solution :)

Comment: How about try to create `a` is a child of postID? We will have dup `a`. But can be order by `a`

Comment: @tuledev not sure what you are saying but I changed my code to create a table specially dedicated to the tags it's easier even if it takes a little more space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Hristo Eftimov I change my way to stock the tags in order to have a better access. I did that by creating different table for tag that is more easy to access and doesn't need an particular index

[Firebase .indexOn dynamic keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238374/firebase-indexon-dynamic-keys?noredirect=1&lq=1)